# How can I improve the efficiency of this SQL query that goes over 4 tables and has multiple nested statments

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MIN(tL.id) AS classLessonID,
       tC.class AS className,
       CONCAT((SELECT term
                 FROM hl_classes_term
                WHERE active = '1'),
              LPAD((SELECT COUNT(*) as num
                      FROM hl_classes_lessons
                     WHERE class_id = tC.id
                       AND id <= MIN(tL.id)), 2, '0')) AS classLessonNum
  FROM hl_classes_lessons tL, hl_classes tC
 WHERE tL.id NOT IN (SELECT lesson_id
                       FROM hl_classes_answers
                      WHERE student = '".USER_ID."')
   AND tL.term_id = (SELECT id
                       FROM hl_classes_term
                      WHERE active = '1')
   AND tL.class_id = tC.id
 GROUP BY tL.class_id
```

Just looking at that I know I made you cringe.  How can I make that SQL query more efficient.  Right now it runs fast but that is because I don't have a lot of rows in my table.  I guess to answer this question you will need to know more about my database.

I am using MySQL.  I have four tables:

- hl_classes (int id, int professor, varchar class, text description)
- hl_classes_lessons (int id, int class_id, int term_id, varchar lessonTitle, varchar lexiconLink, text lessonData)
- hl_classes_answers (int id, int lesson_id, int student, text submit_answer, int percent)
- hl_classes_terms (int id, datetime createtime, varchar label, int term, int active)

hl_classes stores all of the classes on the website.

The lessons are the individual lessons for each class.  A class can have infinite lessons.  Each lesson is available in a specific term.

hl_classes_terms stores a list of all the terms and the current term has the field active = '1'.

When a user submits their answers to a lesson it is stored in hl_classes_answers.  A user can only answer each lesson once.  Lessons have to be answered sequentially.

Going back to my query it should be doing the following: Select the next lesson the user (USER_ID) has to answer, for each class, in the current term.  Only select the next lesson, get the unique lesson id, get the class name and then the special number we use to show the "lesson" to the users.  The number is a combination of term + (left padded 0) lesson n.  Ie, First term, first lesson is 101.  4th term, 12th lesson is 412.

Currently this query works but I would like to know how to make it run more efficiently.

Comment: Your DB schema has a chicken-and-egg problem: you don't know that a student is taking a specific class until they have successfully submitted an answer - so you can't tell them which classes they are supposed to be able to enter answers for.  Once they've submitted their first answer for a particular class, then you can continue, but how are they identified as taking the class?

Comment: But students are supposed to take every class.  If they have yet to submit answers for a class it's just that they have to to answer the first lesson.

Comment: OK - that was not clear.  It is an unusual organization that employs professors and yet has every student taking every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that could make a big difference in query efficiency:

1. **The subquery in the SELECT** - that subquery is getting run for every single row in your result set.  That could add up to quite a lot.  Better to create a single subquery that can be joined on to your main query as a table:

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM hl_classes_lessons tL
    JOIN hl_classes tC ON tL.class_id = tC.id
    JOIN (
    SELECT id, class_id COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM hl_classes_lessons
    ) AS awesome_join ON awesome_join.class_id = tC.id AND awesome_join.id [less than or equal to] MIN(tL.id)
    WHERE ...
```

1. **Poor FROM clause** - avoid using the SELECT ... FROM table1,table2,table3 syntax.  Instead. do something like

```
    FROM hl_classes_lessons tL
    JOIN hl_classes tC ON tL.class_id = tC.id
    WHERE   tL.id NOT IN (  SELECT lesson_id
               FROM hl_classes_answers
               WHERE student = ".USER_ID." )
    AND tL.term_id = ( SELECT id
               FROM hl_classes_term
               WHERE active = 1 )
```

After fixing those, I would verify that the relevant columns had indexes on them (hl_classes_lessons.class_id, hl_classes.id).  Run your query with an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) to see if there is an index that should be getting used, but isn't for some reason.

And lastly, I would [avoid enclosing integers in single quotes](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/beware-of-implicit-casting).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am understand the changes to the FROM clause as well as the part on integers in single quotes.  I am not sure about modifying my SELECT clause with a JOIN in it.  Do you know of any tutorials that explain that?

Comment: You can JOIN a subquery onto your main query as if it were a table - I've updated the first example, hopefully that will make it a bit clearer.  Such subqueries are called table subqueries, or derived tables.

Comment: You could also probably lump those two nested queries in the from clause with and EXIST clause

Answer (score 1):

I created a set of tables and some sample data, as shown below.

### 2nd Edition

With the extra information that every student is supposed to take every class, then the query below works correctly for students with no answers submitted or with some answers submitted.  It does not detect when the student has submitted answers for all lessons in a given class.

```
SELECT AL.Class_ID,
       C.Class,
       100 * T.Term + AL.NextLessonNum AS ClassLessonNum
  FROM (SELECT L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID, COUNT(A.Lesson_ID) + 1 AS NextLessonNum
          FROM hl_classes_lessons AS L
          LEFT JOIN hl_classes_answers AS A
            ON A.Lesson_ID = L.ID AND A.Student = 221
         GROUP BY L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID
       ) AS AL
  JOIN hl_classes       AS C ON C.ID = AL.Class_ID
  JOIN hl_classes_terms AS T ON T.ID = AL.Term_ID  AND T.Active = 1;
```

Next answers to be submitted by student 221:

```
724    History    102
722    Maths 1    101
723    English    102
721    Physics    103
```

Query for student 220:

```
SELECT AL.Class_ID,
       C.Class,
       100 * T.Term + AL.NextLessonNum AS ClassLessonNum
  FROM (SELECT L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID, COUNT(A.Lesson_ID) + 1 AS NextLessonNum
          FROM hl_classes_lessons AS L
          LEFT JOIN hl_classes_answers AS A
            ON A.Lesson_ID = L.ID AND A.Student = 220
         GROUP BY L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID
       ) AS AL
  JOIN hl_classes       AS C ON C.ID = AL.Class_ID
  JOIN hl_classes_terms AS T ON T.ID = AL.Term_ID  AND T.Active = 1;
```

Student 220 has submitted no answers as yet:

```
724    History    101
722    Maths 1    101
723    English    101
721    Physics    101
```

---

### 1st Edition

I think this query produces correct results for any given student - the example here uses student 221:

```
SELECT AL.Class_ID,
       C.Class,
       100 * T.Term + AL.NextLessonNum AS ClassLessonNum
  FROM (SELECT L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID, COUNT(*) + 1 AS NextLessonNum
          FROM hl_classes_answers AS A
          JOIN hl_classes_lessons AS L ON A.Lesson_ID = L.ID AND A.Student = 221
         GROUP BY L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID
       ) AS AL
  JOIN hl_classes       AS C ON C.ID = AL.Class_ID
  JOIN hl_classes_terms AS T ON T.ID = AL.Term_ID  AND T.Active = 1;
```

For the data below, the result is:

```
724    History    102
723    English    102
721    Physics    103
```

That looks correct to me.  The general version of the query (not constrained to one student) looks like:

```
SELECT AL.Student,
       AL.Class_ID,
       C.Class,
       100 * T.Term + AL.NextLessonNum AS ClassLessonNum
  FROM (SELECT A.Student, L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID, COUNT(*) + 1 AS NextLessonNum
          FROM hl_classes_answers AS A
          JOIN hl_classes_lessons AS L ON A.Lesson_ID = L.ID
         GROUP BY A.Student, L.Term_ID, L.Class_ID
       ) AS AL
  JOIN hl_classes       AS C ON C.ID = AL.Class_ID
  JOIN hl_classes_terms AS T ON T.ID = AL.Term_ID  AND T.Active = 1
 ORDER BY AL.Student, AL.Class_ID;
```

This yields the result:

```
221    721    Physics    103
221    723    English    102
221    724    History    102
224    721    Physics    102
224    722    Maths 1    102
224    723    English    102
224    724    History    102
227    724    History    103
228    722    Maths 1    102
228    723    English    102
231    721    Physics    102
231    723    English    102
232    722    Maths 1    102
232    724    History    102
233    721    Physics    102
233    723    English    102
```

As noted in a comment to the main question, I believe your DB schema has a chicken-and-egg problem: you don't know that a student is taking a specific class until they have successfully submitted an answer - so you can't tell them which classes they are supposed to be able to enter answers for before they've got an answer recorded. Once they've submitted their first answer for a particular class, then you can continue, but how are they identified as taking the class?

Consequently, I've not attempted to deal with entering the answer for class 101 - that has to be added to the DB by some other technique.

I've also not attempted to deal with the situation where the student has submitted answers for all lessons in a particular class.

---

### Tables

#### hl_classes_terms

```
create table hl_classes_terms
(
    id         int primary key,
    createtime timestamp, -- datetime year to second,
    label      varchar(15),
    term       int,
    active     int
);
```

#### hl_classes

```
create table hl_classes
(
    id          int primary key,
    professor   int,
    class       varchar(25),
    description varchar(50)
);
```

#### hl_classes_lessons

```
create table hl_classes_lessons
(
     id          int primary key,
     class_id    int,
     term_id     int,
     lessonTitle varchar(25),
     lexiconLink varchar(25),
     lessonData varchar(25)
);
```

#### hl_classes_answers

```
create table hl_classes_answers
(
    id            int primary key,
    lesson_id     int,
    student       int,
    submit_answer varchar(255),
    percent       int
);
```

### Data

#### hl_classes_terms

CURRENT is the way the DBMS I use (IBM Informix Dynamic Server) spells the current timestamp.

```
insert into hl_classes_terms values(345, current, "michaelmas", 1, 1);
insert into hl_classes_terms values(346, current, "lent",       2, 0);
insert into hl_classes_terms values(347, current, "summer",     3, 0);
insert into hl_classes_terms values(348, current, "stray",      4, 0);
```

#### hl_classes

```
insert into hl_classes values(721, 1, "Physics", "Physics");
insert into hl_classes values(722, 5, "Maths 1", "Maths 1");
insert into hl_classes values(723, 2, "English", "English");
insert into hl_classes values(724, 5, "History", "History");
```

#### hl_classes_lessons

```
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(913, 721, 345, "Physics L1", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(914, 724, 345, "History L1", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(915, 722, 345, "Maths   L1", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(916, 723, 345, "English L1", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(917, 721, 345, "Physics L2", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(918, 724, 345, "History L2", "link", "data");
insert into hl_classes_lessons values(919, 721, 345, "Physics L3", "link", "data");
```

#### hl_classes_answers

```
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1211, 913, 221, "Answer", 20);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1212, 917, 221, "Answer", 30);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1213, 914, 221, "Answer", 40);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1214, 916, 221, "Answer", 50);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1215, 913, 224, "Answer", 60);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1216, 914, 224, "Answer", 70);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1217, 915, 224, "Answer", 80);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1218, 916, 224, "Answer", 90);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1219, 914, 227, "Answer", 50);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1220, 918, 227, "Answer", 60);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1221, 915, 228, "Answer", 70);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1222, 916, 228, "Answer", 80);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1223, 916, 231, "Answer", 90);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1224, 913, 231, "Answer", 80);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1225, 914, 232, "Answer", 70);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1226, 915, 232, "Answer", 60);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1227, 916, 233, "Answer", 50);
insert into hl_classes_answers values(1228, 913, 233, "Answer", 40);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but that query doesn't quite work.  Based on the sub query it will only select classes you have submitted at least one answer to.